# How to mount FAT16/32 USB volume on smartos/illumos/omnios?

Tags: usb, mount, hypervisor, opensolaris, fat16

I'm trying to copy a file from a Windows 10 Laptop to a SmartOS installation on PC. I have copied the file on to a USB stick. I would like to mount that on SmartOS from root zone (root login), access and copy the file over to a location on the primary SSD (some path on the main system). Can someone give me the necessary information/steps to accomplish this? If this is not the right place to ask this, where is a better place?

EDIT:
@Ramhound, I hate to hear that question when I clearly have no idea where to begin even. But even without understanding what I was doing, I did try quite a number of different things. FYI, I'm not familiar with Solaris or Illumos or SmartOS or OmniOS.

I have tried mounting in various ways, but I have no clear idea what commands to use. I have tried some commands that are said to work on Solaris systems, Illumos etc. I was just trying things blindly.

http://wiki-ux.info/wiki/How_to_mount_a_USB_flash_drive_under_Solaris

mount -F pcfs /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0p0:c /mnt
mount /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0p0 /mnt

The above device name is different from actual. The original command had dsk but I tried changing dsk to rdsk as above. I have no clear idea what the p0 and :c are supposed to represent. Maybe p stands for partition? Also, I didn't understand why volmgt stop has to be issued.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54782/devusbtasks-22.html

rmmount /dev/dsk/c3t0d0p0:1

But rmmount is not available.

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2103810&seqNum=7

But I don't know what stripes are. The only striping I know of has to do with raid.

BTW, I got the requirement to copy the file over because I didn't know how to directly download the file on SmartOS. This started with me trying to download a file with curl and curl complaining sa-certificates.crt was not found. I didn't want to fallback to http. The solution I could think of was to copy the cacert.pem file over from the Windows PC.

I mean, I clearly don't know what I'm doing. The question of what I have already tried is irrelevant, except maybe to test whether I had actually made any effort.

Now if it was like mounting a device on linux, I might have been able to figure it out on my own, but here, nothing I tried seemed to work, and I couldn't figure out how to fill in the gaps in my knowledge and understanding.

Comment: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound, see the edit. Did you ask because you're in a position to help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look through the wiki-ux link and tired a method where I used `iostat -En` to find out the name of the drive, used cd and ls to look in the /dev/dsk directory to confirm that said name is there and then typed
`mount -F pcfs /dev/dsk/c2t0d0p0:c /mnt`
When I looked in the /mnt directory and used ls to inspect the contents, the USB files were there.
This was on Omni OS with a FAT32 USB btw